# How to disable Touch ID prompt in Apple Research Kit?

Tags: researchkit

Using ORKPasscodeStep, after entering a passcode I get a "Passcode Saved" message and then a "Please authenticate with Touch ID" popup dialog. Is there a way to avoid prompting for Touch ID?

Answer (score 0):

In ORKPasscodeStepViewController.m (found under Common/Step/Passcode Step), there's an attribute called _useTouchId. If you set it to false:

```
_useTouchId = NO;
```

TouchID should be disabled and won't be asked. You will have to reinstall your app from your test device or simulator, otherwise, it will continue asking for TouchID. There are disadvantages with this approach, namely that you will have to go into ResearchKit and change the attribute every time you pull from Git or update your ReseachKit framework.